# NgRx sort and update Array inside object in state

Tags: angular, ngrx

Cant assign sorted array back to state.

The interface type IDataSet assigned to the subComponentData looks like this.  arrOut is sorted but if I try to assign it back to gridDataArray it does not work.  I get a type mismatch {}[] is not [{}].

```
export interface IDataSet {
gridDataArray: [
    {
        column1: string;
        column2: string;
        column3: string;
        column4: string;
        column5: string;
        name: string;
    }
];
urls: string[];
}
```

State object looks like this.

```
export interface IFeatureState {
  subComponentData: IDataSet;
  isSpinnerActivated: boolean;
}
```

Assigning the little test data I have below does work.  But if I try and assign "arrOut" or "arr" back it does not compile and I get this error.

The types of 'subComponentData.gridDataArray' are incompatible between these types. Type '{ column1: string; column2: string; column3: string; column4: string; column5: string; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '[{ column1: string; column2: string; column3: string; column4: string; column5: string; name: string; }]'

```
on(sortGridData, (state: IFeatureState, { payload } ) => {
    const sortByKey = key => (a, b) => a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : -1;
    const arr = state.subComponentData.gridDataArray.slice();
    const arrOut = arr.sort(sortByKey(payload));
   return {
        ...state,
        subComponentData: {
            ...state.subComponentData,
            gridDataArray: arrOut

            //TEST DATA THAT WORKS
            // [{ column1:'Test', column2: 'Test', column3: 'Test',
            //     column4: 'Test', column5: 'Test', name: 'Test' }]
        }
    };
}),
```

Comment: I just found that if I take my TEST DATA above and add one more of the same objects to the array it is in it does not work.  It says it only expects 1 item not 2.

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED

```
export interface IDataSet {
   gridDataArray: IDataElement[];
   urls: string[];
}

export interface IDataElement

{
    column1: string;
    column2: string;
    column3: string;
    column4: string;
    column5: string;
    name: string;
}
```

Then in the reducer just changed to this:

```
  on(sortGridData, (state: IFeatureState, { payload } ) => {
  const sortByKey = key => (a, b) => a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : -1;
  const arr = state.subComponentData.gridDataArray.slice();
  const arrOut = arr.sort(sortByKey(payload));
 return {
    ...state,
    subComponentData: {
        ...state.subComponentData,
        gridDataArray: [...arrOut]
    }
};
```

}),

I was very close but owe the answer to this.
Now my sort only goes in one direction so I will be working on that next.

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-source-has-elements-but-target-allows